# Azure QnA Merging Same Questions

Tags: azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

We are uploading a PDF with semi structured Question & Answers. QnA maker is merging same question if they are successive. If there is some other question exist between them, then QnA maker is not merging same questions. For example.

> Q Machine was not able to be started
>
> Answer 1
>
> Q Machine was not able to be started
>
> Answer 2
>
> Q Burning plastic smell on machine
>
> Answer 3

Now the QnA Maker will train it like this

> Q Machine was not able to be started
>
> Answer 1
>
> Answer 2
>
> Q Burning plastic smell on machine
>
> Answer 3

Why is QnA is behaving like this and how to separate same questions. Help is required.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. QnA works on the 'one question (and related, similar questions)' to one answer idea, and expects unique questions for the queries. The QnA documentation states:

> A knowledge base consists of question and answer (QnA) sets. Each set has one answer and a set contains all the information associated with that answer. An answer can loosely resemble a database row or a data structure instance.
>
> The required settings in a question-and-answer (QnA) set are:
>
> - a question - text of user query, used to QnA Maker's machine-learning, to align with text of user's question with different wording but the same answer
> - the answer - the set's answer is the response that's returned when a user query is matched with the associated question
>     Each set is represented by an ID.
>
> The optional settings for a set include:
>
> - Alternate forms of the question - this helps QnA Maker return the correct answer for a wider variety of question phrasings
> - Metadata: Metadata are tags associated with a QnA pair and are represented as key-value pairs. Metadata tags are used to filter QnA pairs and limit the set over which query matching is performed.
> - Multi-turn prompts, used to continue a multi-turn conversation

QnA Maker doesn't differentiate between the two questions because *it isn't two questions*. It's literally the same question with two different answers.

This particular case would be a good use of QnAMaker's multi-turn prompt feature, where, after the customer has put in the query 'The machine won't start', QnA can follow up with a prompt that says "Which machine did you mean? Machine A or Machine B", and whichever they choose leads to the correct answer. I would look into [Multi-Turn Conversations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/multiturn-conversation) for your knowledgebase.